# How to make .nuproj projects work with NCrunch

Tags: msbuild, mstest, ncrunch, nuproj

I have a solution with two nuproj projects, say A and B.
Both projects contain only props and targets files (so NO assemblies or PDB files) and they both generate NuGet packages.

Now, A has no reference and it is an internal dependency, whereas B references A plus other external NuGets.
Then I have an MSTest project that dynamically invokes MSBuild on a project which references B.

All works fine in Visual Studio and the tests pass. However, NCrunch compiles with warnings for the project B.

WARNING - ........\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (2110, 5): MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'A.nupckg' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Infact, **no NuGet package is generated for the A project** in the NCrunch solution directory (the package is correctly generated in Visual Studio).

I have also tried to set the following properties for the A and B projects:

- Instrument assembly = false
- Prevent signing of output assembly = false
- Implicit project dependencies = true

nothing changes and the warning is still there and no NuGet is generated for the A project (all the source files and dependent assemblies are in the NCrunch solution folder).
And Copy referenced assemblies to workspace is set to true.

Is there any known issue with using NCrunch with .nuproj?

Comment: Maybe post this question on ncrunch forum: https://forum.ncrunch.net/ Author is pretty active in there.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, will do it.

Comment: It turns out .nuproj projects are not supported by NCrunch yet.
Thanks for the suggestion :)